# Which task should I choose for my SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am completely new to SSIS, in fact the below wold be my first SSIS package.

I have following requirement:

"I have to read two column from the table, let say EmployeeId (Integer) and FileBytes (Image).
 Then, I have to create document for each Employee reading the FileBytes, (ex: Employee01.doc) in a folder."

Things, I have:

As I am a pure .NET guy I have prepared a .NET code which is reading bytes and saving as a doc file in the folder. 
I have SQL Script to read bytes from the table (a simple select statement)

Please suggest me which task I select to do my stuff, am I correct with the below task list:

1. Execute SQL Task (which will create a table of all Emp, and bytes)
2. Script Task (Which will take the value from the variable generated from the SQL task, one by one and process them)

I am seeking help so that I can understand which task should I use and for what purpose, rest I will do.. because I want to learn SSIS !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a few (read: 3), but I'll do my best to try to help you out here.

Generally, I use a "Execute SQL" task right away if I need to do something like clear-out a temp table.  Next, I'll create a "Data Flow" task and connect my Execute SQL task to it.  Then, click on the "Data Flow" tab to do the rest.

Here's where the fun begins...  On the [Data Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140080.aspx) tab, you can set up multiple independent data tasks.  First create a "Data Source" component.  You can drag/drop that from your Toolbox.  Configure it to access a specific database, and then set it to return a table or data by a specific query.

If you have decisions to make about the data, you can direct its output to a "[Lookup Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx)".  You can use that to filter-out things like only new rows, or rows that errored or didn't match.  Similarly, you could also use a "[Conditional Split Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137886.aspx)" to send data to different outputs.

Finally when you're ready to apply an update, you can route your data flow to an destination (ADO NET, flat file, Excel, etc...).

As for the "Script Task" you should really only use that for a script that needs to be run once.  If you need something run once per-row, you should use the "[Script Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137640.aspx)" inside your Data Flow.  It has an input, but can also be used like a data source.

[MSDN also has this SSIS tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx) that should help to get you started, too.

Comment: +1 Wow! That's pretty interesting. I am going to start working on this. I have a question though, if you don't mind. As my select statement (i.e. **SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM TABLE**) returns multiple rows, can I do like this to loop rows one by one instead of handling with a complete result set (of 1000 rows) ?

Comment: Will this feed up my curiosity ? http://www.select-sql.com/mssql/loop-through-ado-recordset-in-ssis.html

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite I believe the exact way that MSDN puts it is "If you have to use the script to do the same work for each row of data in a set, you should use the Script component instead of the Script task."  Does that answer your question?